# angularJS good practise: how to create controllers for complex application?

Tags: angularjs

let assume I need to create a dashboard application that includes users, tasks and messages. I have a theoric knowledge of angularJS only, not real life application and I don't know exactly how to architect an angular application.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="users" ng-controller="usersController"></div>
    <div id="tasks" ng-controller="tasksController"></div>
    <div id="messages" ng-controller="messagesController"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{id:1, username:'john'},{id:2, username:'jack'}];
});

myApp.controller('tasksController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.addTask = function(userid, task) {
    }
});

myApp.controller('messagesController', function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = [];
    $scope.addMessage = function(userid, message) {     
    }   
});
```

I just cannot figure out how taskController can speak with usersContoller or Taskcontroller.
Or should I use something like

```
myApp.users = {};
myApp.tasks = {};
myApp.messages = {};
```

Or should I use a service for that ?

and finally how to watch for changes on that users, tasks and messages.

Comment: I'd recommend starting here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md for guidance on application architecture.

Comment: If you're learning Angular then I would suggest not using $scope. Set a variable to the scope of your controller at the top 'var vm = this;' [javascript] then set all your scope variables to vm.VARIABLENAME. In your view use the controllerAs syntax and you'll have access 'ng-controller="myController as vm' [html].

Comment: ok: what about watching changes in users, tasks, messages ?